# RMI program Rebind error

Tags: java, rmi

I have a big problem with my code it seems. I get this :

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 5.12.78.59; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
    at Server.main(Server.java:9)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
    at Server.main(Server.java:9)
    at __SHELL7.run(__SHELL7.java:6)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:725)
```

on the code below:

```
public class Server {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Generator Ob = new Generator();
    System.out.println("1");
    Naming.rebind("rmi:///Ob",Ob);

    System.out.println("Serverul s-a legat la" +
                       " registrul RMI");
  }
}
```

Generator is defined correctly yet when i do Naming.rebind it all falls apart , why ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you initialized the `RMI` registry?

Comment: yes i did do that in cmd rmiregistry , and then java Server and i got that error :P. this is what you were trying to tell me or i am total idiot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Registry isn't running when you do the rebind. I know what it says in your comment above but the evidence is unmistakeable.

Comment: ok so to start the Registry then : i open CMD, i go D:\java\bin start registry 1111 , I then open the server. I am not doing this right am I?

Comment: `start registry 1111` doesn't start the RMI Registry. It starts some other program called `registry`, which may not even exist. If you correct it to `start rmiregistry `1111,` it starts a Registry listening on port 1111, which isn't the default assumed by `Naming.bind()` so your application still won't work. Try `start rmiregistry`.